# How to fix seemingly endless loop while creating virtual environment with python 3?

Tags: python, virtualenv

Cmd prompt says Running `virtualenv with interpreter c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe` repeatedly and never creates virtual environment.

I've tried upgrading pip and python, and running variations of the command `virtualenv mypython`

`virtualenv mypython`

I expect a folder with the name following the command `virtualenv` to be created.

But the actual result is this:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe
Running virtualenv with interpreter c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe
Running virtualenv with interpreter c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe
Running virtualenv with interpreter c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe
Running virtualenv with interpreter c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe
Running virtualenv with interpreter c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe
Running virtualenv with interpreter c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe
```

Until i hit `ctrl-c` which gives this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 19, in <module>
    import base64
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 963, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 906, in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1280, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1252, in _get_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1364, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 81, in _path_stat
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 2611, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 815, in main
    raise SystemExit(sub_process_call.wait())
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in wait
    return self._wait(timeout=timeout)
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1230, in _wait
    timeout_millis)
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 2611, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 815, in main
    raise SystemExit(sub_process_call.wait())
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in wait
    return self._wait(timeout=timeout)
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1230, in _wait
    timeout_millis)
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 2611, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 815, in main
    raise SystemExit(sub_process_call.wait())
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in wait
    return self._wait(timeout=timeout)
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1230, in _wait
    timeout_millis)
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 2611, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 815, in main
    raise SystemExit(sub_process_call.wait())
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in wait
    return self._wait(timeout=timeout)
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1230, in _wait
    timeout_millis)
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 2611, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 815, in main
    raise SystemExit(sub_process_call.wait())
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in wait
    return self._wait(timeout=timeout)
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1230, in _wait
    timeout_millis)
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 2611, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 815, in main
    raise SystemExit(sub_process_call.wait())
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in wait
    return self._wait(timeout=timeout)
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1230, in _wait
    timeout_millis)
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\di203179\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\virtualenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 815, in main
    raise SystemExit(sub_process_call.wait())
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in wait
    return self._wait(timeout=timeout)
  File "c:\users\di203179\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1230, in _wait
    timeout_millis)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Proably you're using the version 16.6.1 of the virtualenv module which causes that bug, try using the following code to install 16.6.0:

```
 pip install virtualenv==16.6.0
```

Then try to create the virtual enviroment again.

Answer (score 0):

Out of virtualenv update to version 16.0.2. 
Try: 
pip install virtualenv --upgrade